# Conda(mini) hangs Collecting package metadata when creating 2 environments on the same script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, anaconda, conda, amazon-sagemaker

We need to create(and install packages on) 2 conda(we are using mini-conda) environments on the same shell script(AWS linux instance for Sagemaker), the first creation and package installation works fine, but for the second, it hangs forever in

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

I know this has been discussed(and some solutions proposed) before, but none has worked for me, according to some of the workarounds I have tried:

- Remove conda-forge from the channels: this created a version incompatibility nightmare, and some of the needed packages are not in the base channels.
- conda config --set channel_priority flexible: did not try it because conda config --describe channel_priority shows it is already flexible.
- Add more RAM: I doubled memory and the problem still persists
- edit conda/conda/core/subdir_data.py and change the line  and modify the line Executor = (DummyExecutor if context.debug or context.repodata_threads == 1
- Install and use Mamba: it got errors and inconsistencies warnings, searching for the errors I found mamba only works with python 2.7(I need python>=3.7)
- Probably some others I don't remember

Has anyone installed more than 1 conda env. using a single script? Any ideas on how to fix the that hanging issue?

**Update:** in case someone else finds this issue, after trying everything without success, by chance we remove one package(snowflake connector) in the script(removed the conda install) and then the installation proceeded, then it got stuck again when checking the logs it was the snowflake-sql alchemy), not sure if it is just a coincidence that both packages are related to snowflake, but removed them from conda and installed them with pip and the script works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved adding `conda clean --all` after creating the first env and before the second.